# Сортировка с сохранением позиции

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сортировка, qt5, c++17

Есть ли стандартная функция которая позволяет отсортировать массив (вектор или список) с сохранением индексов или как сделать такую сортировку в "две строки"?

```
std::list<int> src {1, 8, 3, 6, 5};
std::list<uint> res = magicFunc(&src);
// src == [ 1, 3, 5, 6, 8]
// res == [ 0, 2, 4, 3, 1]
```

Comment: стандартной вроде бы нет, но сделать руками буквально 2 строки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант - сортировать вектор индексов со своей функцией сравнение.

```
vector<int> src = { 1, 8, 3, 12, 5, 9 };
vector<int> res = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
sort(res.begin(), res.end(),
     [&src](int i, int j) {
         return src[i] < src[j];
    });

for (int i : res) cout << i << "  ";

cout << endl;
```

Comment: Ну или map пришить